# Retq instruction, where does it return

Tags: assembly, x86-64, stack-overflow, inline-assembly

I am unable to understand where the assembly instruction `retq` returns to.

I understand that when my normal code executes then it return to the address specified in the stack. But how does it know where in the stack is the return address located?

In short, does it use rbp or esp for finding the address on the stack?

Comment: If you want to experiment, try replacing `retq` with `addq $8, %rsp; jmpq -8(%rsp)`. Functionally equivalent (not performance-wise though).

Comment: `ret` doesn't affect FLAGS, so the actual drop-in replacement uses `lea 8(%rsp), %rsp` instead of `add`.  And this is only safe in user-space in the x86-64 System V calling convention, where you have a red-zone below RSP that's safe from asynchronous clobbers (e.g. by signal handlers and debuggers).  On Windows, an SEH exception could potentially be delivered between `lea` and `ret`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After studying assembly code, here are my thoughts,
let's look at a sample:

```
fun:
push %rbp
mov %rsp,%rbp
...
...
pop %rbp
retq

main:
...
...
callq  "address" <fun>
...
...
```

We can see there is a instruction before `retq`. The `pop %rbp` (sometimes it is a leave instruction but they are similar) instruction will

1. save the content of current stack pointer `%rsp` to base stack pointer `%rbp`.
2. move the `%rsp` pointer to previous address on stack.

For example: before pop command, the `%rsp` pointed to `0x0000 0000 0000 00D0`. After the `pop` command it points to `0x0000 0000 0000 00D8`  (assume the stack grows from high address to low address).

After the `pop` command, now `%rsp` points to a new address and `retq` takes this address as return address.

Answer (score 4):

`ret` is how you spell `pop rip` on x86: a stack pop and an indirect branch to that value.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ret documents exactly what it does and doesn't do.

It's effectively `pop %tmp` / `jmp *%tmp` where `tmp` is an internal temporary register.

`ret` depends only on RSP.

Using RBP as a frame pointer is a totally optional software convention that modern compilers don't even do when optimization is enabled.